# iPhone viewport on desktop

Tags: iphone, jquery-mobile

How can I set my viewport on my desktop (while developing my app) to the iPhone screen size, without touching the CSS?

I'm developing my app with jQueryMobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old-fashioned definition of the viewport (before scaling and the `viewport` meta tag became common with the iPhone) is just the size of the `html` element. So you can just style it as follows:

```
html {
    position: absolute;
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
}
```

Alternatively, use a browser extension (like the “Web Developer Toolbar” for Firefox to resize your browser window to the size you want your viewport to have.

Answer (score 0):

Why not detect if it is an iphone or a browser and then style accordingly, like;

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/i) ? true : false )
{
    //ios detected
}
else
{
    //no ios detected, add css to set the dimensions of the body
}
```

This way, the css would only be affected in a browser

Comment: Isn't there a way to temporarily add meta tags while developing and when going live delete those tagS? That would be more useful in my case